# Read the content of Play Store web page to show a "new updated available" dialog

Tags: android, html

I've published an app in Play Store (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pikotech.bo2guide), so I've seen the number of updates is so slow, and this is a problem because I release a lot of them.
I would show a "New updated available" dialog that redirect the user to my app's PlayStore tab.
To do this I've thought a system to parse the source(Command+Alt+U in OS X Chrome) of my app's PlayStore Web Page. The info that stores my app's version available is this:

```
<dd itemprop="softwareVersion">1.0.6</dd>
```

or this

```
<div class="goog-menuitem" data-paramValue="7"><div
```

How to compare on of these values with the version installed of the app? If the content parsed will be higher of the version installed, I will show a dialog with "new updated avaialble", that can redirect the user on PlayStore to updated my app.